# Many if statements within an interval function, one works but more not?

Tags: if-statement, intervals

My requirement is that every few seconds my div tag slide to the left (margin-left).

I think the code is self-explaining.

Is there something that I am missing?

Is it because of the numerous if statements?

Or is there an easier, smarter function?

```
setInterval(function(){
  if ($(".carousel").css("margin-left")!='0%'){
      $(".carousel").css("margin-left", "-100%");
  }
  if ($(".carousel").css("margin-left")!='-100%'){
      $(".carousel").css("margin-left", "-200%");
  }
  if ($(".carousel").css("margin-left")!='-200%'){
      $(".carousel").css("margin-left", "-300%");
  }
  if ($(".carousel").css("margin-left")!='-300%'){
      $(".carousel").css("margin-left", "-400%");
  }
  if ($(".carousel").css("margin-left")!='-400%'){
      $(".carousel").css("margin-left", "-500%");
  }
  if ($(".carousel").css("margin-left")!='-500%'){
      $(".carousel").css("margin-left", "-600%");
  }
  if ($(".carousel").css("margin-left")!='-600%'){
      $(".carousel").css("margin-left", "-700%");
  }
  if ($(".carousel").css("margin-left")!='-700%'){
      $(".carousel").css("margin-left", "0%");
  }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're using `!=` instead of the expected `==`.

Also, if you make this change, you'll have to properly chain your `if` statements to use `else if` otherwise, as it stands, changing from `0%` to `-100%` will trigger the if statement for `-100%` to `-200%` and so on.

On the other hand, a simpler function might be the following:

**This has been updated due to the comment thread below.**

```
function setCarouselMargin(marginLeft) {
    $('.carousel').css('margin-left', marginLeft + '%');

    marginLeft -= 100;

    if (marginLeft < -700) {
        marginLeft = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(function () { setCarouselMargin(marginLeft) }, 2000);
}

$(function() {
    setCarouselMargin(0);
});
```

Comment: The problem is I have no context to work with. Just saying "it doesn't work" gives me no idea as to what the problem is. Does manually changing the margin-left using developer tools work as you expect?

Comment: yes this works, here is the context

<ul class="carousel">
<li>...
</ul>

this ul had a width of 800% of the parent element.

and it should slide every 2 seconds -100% more to the left.

and in my external js:


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

setInterval(
    function () {
        var marginLeft = parseInt($('.carousel').css('margin-left'));

        marginLeft -= 100;

        if (marginLeft < 700) {
            marginLeft = 0;
        }

        $('.carousel').css('margin-left', marginLeft + '%');
    },
    2000
);


});

Comment: That `if (marginLeft < 700)` should be `if (marginLeft < -700)`.

Comment: I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrMkM/1/) that works. It uses a separate function to handle state as internally the `margin-left` is converted to a pixel value which breaks my function above.

Comment: Yeah now it moves, the first slide looks good, then is spring directly to 7 and back to 1